# pushback to vector in Golang causes program crash

Tags: go

```
func extract_word(r rune) bool {
    return !unicode.IsLetter(r)
}
type kv_string_value struct {
    str string
    num int
}

func Map(value string) *list.List {

    t := strings.FieldsFunc(value, extract_word)
        fmt.Println("t:", len(t))
        m := make(map[string]int)
    for _, word  := range t{
            m[word]++   
    }
    var x *list.List

        for k,v := range m {
        pair := kv_string_value{}
                pair.str = k
                pair.num = v
        x.PushBack(pair)
        fmt.Println("Good5")
    }

    return x
}
```

Something wrong with this "x.PushBack(pair)"

it just pushback a pair to a list, why it crash my program?
need help.
thanks!

```
  /main$ go run wc.go master kjv12.txt sequential
    # command-line-arguments
    ./wc.go:34: *x.PushBack(pair) evaluated but not used
  main$ go run wc.go master kjv12.txt sequential
    Split kjv12.txt
    name is mrtmp.kjv12.txt-0
    DoMap: read split mrtmp.kjv12.txt-0 966967
    Read succesful.
    t: 160040
    panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
    [signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x444c25]

    goroutine 1 [running]:
    runtime.panic(0x6874a0, 0x9c5a48)
        /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/runtime/panic.c:266 +0xb6
    container/list.(*List).lazyInit(0x0)
        /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/container/list/list.go:86 +0x5
    container/list.(*List).PushBack(0x0, 0x68ce20, 0xc210084240, 0x2)
        /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/container/list/list.go:138 +0x27
```

Comment: Could you please start from reading a book or other introductory material on Go first, as has been already suggested? I'm sorry but your questions reduce the signal-to-noise ratio of the stream of questions tagged `go`.  Trivial problems like this one do really mandate [you doing your own research first](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  Please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bug lies in:

```
var x *list.List
```

You declare a pointer to a `list.List` without creating an instance of it. `x` will have the initial value of `nil`. To make your code work, change the line to:

```
x := list.New()
```

Comment: @NoName Welcome :) . Remember to accept the answer you decide to use in your questions.

Comment: While you're not wholly incorrect, the `list` package has a `New` method which probably should be called instead of using the `new` builtin, in case the package needs to initialize the `List` somehow, in fact if you look at the source for the package, `list.New()` is defined as `return new(List).Init()` so some setup is required.

Comment: @Jsor I made a too quick assumption there. Yes, calling list.New() is the way to go as it sets `next` and `prev` to the root. I updated the answer.